# How to figure out Space complexity of a program

Tags: c++

How to figure out space complexity of any program. 
Like if I have the following code. what would be its space complexity?

```
sum=0;
for(I=0; J<n; I++)
{
    for(j=0; j<I*I; j++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<j; k++)
        {
            sum++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do your own homework?

Comment: Do you mean _time_ complexity/

Comment: I mean the amount of memory it needs to run to completion

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a constant number of variables, its space complexity is O(1)